# como actualizar una tabla de una una base de datos mysql con Angular y Laravel

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Laravel y angular, estoy trayendo los datos con Laravel y los muestro con Angular.

Controllador en laravel:

```
public function ListadoDimensiones(){
    $dimensiones = Dimension::with(['categorias' => function($q){
        $q->with(['propiedades'=>function($r){
            $r->with(['variables'=>function($s){
                $s->with('intervalostec');
            }]);
        }]);
    }])->get();
    return $dimensiones;
}
```

Así traigo los datos con el javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('dimensionesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.variables = [];
  $http.get("/listadoDimensiones")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.dimensiones = response.data;
  });
```

Todo lo anterior es la forma de traer los datos con el laravel y el angular,
lo que quisiera saber como podría crear un función ya sea en el controlador de laravel o en javascript para Angular para actualizar los datos mostrados en la base de datos.

gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: aun sigues teniendo el problema?

Comment: si, no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se quiera crear la comunicación entre Laravel y Angular es necesario agregar un middleware de acceso y colocarlo dentro del kernel

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class addHeadersCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

dentro del Kernel

```
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\addHeadersCors::class,
    ];
```

y en el servicio de Angular de esta forma

```
configUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

this.http.get(this.configUrl + 'listadoDimensiones/[id]').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```